# stops getting Geolocation after a while in MAUI (android )

Tags: maui

I have a foreground service that gets the device's location every 5 seconds and sends it to a server, but after a while, the foreground service stops getting the geolocation data.

```
public async Task RunLocation(CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            _stopping = true;
        while (!_stopping)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000, token);

                var request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                var location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, token);

                Console.WriteLine("Got location: " + location);
}}}}
```

Comment: why do you have a `try` block with no `catch`?  What purpose does that serve?  How will you know if there are exceptions?

Comment: Unhandled exception perhaps? How do you know this cycle is still running?